# How to prevent web form from submitting blank fields

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a web form where the user is required to enter information for the following fields: Full Name, Contact Number and Best Time to Call. Once these fields have been filled the user will submit the form and the data is then added to the database however, my issue right now is that my web form is ignoring the validation i have set and allowing the user to submit a blank web form. I am not sure if it may be the way i have structured my code? nevertheless, how can i resolve this?

**PHP**

```
<?php
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/inc/bootstrap.php');
include("config/cn.php");
$template['template']="page";


    // define variables and set to empty values
    $nameErr = $contactErr = $callErrErr = "";
    $full_name = $contact_number = $best_time_to_call = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{

   if (empty($_POST["full_name"]))
     {$nameErr = "Full name is required";}
   else
     {$full_name = test_input($_POST["full_name"]);}

   if (empty($_POST["contact_number"]))
     {$contactErr = "Contact number is required";}
   else
     {$contact_number = test_input($_POST["contact_number"]);}

   if (empty($_POST["best_time_to_call"]))
     {$callErr = "Must not be left blank";}
   else
     {$best_time_to_call = test_input($_POST["best_time_to_call"]);}


 $enter_sql = "INSERT INTO contact (full_name,contact_number,best_time_to_call) VALUES('$full_name','$contact_number','$best_time_to_call')";
    /*print($enter_sql);*/

    $enter_query = mysql_query($enter_sql) or die(mysql_error());

    header('Location: /thankyou.php');
    exit;


}

function test_input($data)
{
     $data = trim($data);
     $data = stripslashes($data);
     $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
     return $data;
}


?>
```

**HTML**

```
<form name="frmContact" id="frmCallContact" method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" class="TableFormat">
<tr><th align="left" valign="top" colspan="2">Call me back</th></tr>
<tr><td align="right" valign="top">Full Name:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="full_name" id="full_name" style="width:250px;" title="Please enter your full name"/><span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span></td></tr>
<tr>
<td align="right" valign="top">Contact Number:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="contact_number" id="contact_number" style="width:250px;" />
<span class="error">*<?php echo $contactErr;?></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right" valign="top">Best Time to Call:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="best_time_to_call" id="best_time_to_call" style="width:250px;"  title="Please enter your best time to call"/>
<span class="error">*<?php echo $callErr;?></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
<td><!--<a name="submit" href="#"><img src="/img/bn_submit.png" width="93" height="28" /></a>--><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: To summarise your code logic: *test whether the fields are empty or not, set error variables based on that, then regardless of whether there are any errors or not, insert data into the database.* You need another `if` statement to check whether there were any errors...

Comment: Am i not checking if there were any errors already?:S

Comment: Indeed you are not. Read your own code and follow its logic with pen and paper if necessary. Try to simulate in your head what exactly happens when a field is empty.

Comment: Well when a field is empty, what should happen is that an error message should occur and therefore, not allow the user to submit the form without going back and filling in all the blank fields. Correct me if i am wrong, i am guessing that my code checks whether a field is empty but doesn't actually do anything and therefore allows the user to submit the form which is why i would need another if statement that checks whether a field was actually empty and produced an error

Comment: So with the code that i already have, would you say that i'd need to move parts around or leave it how it is and just add another if statement?

Answer (score 0):

```
$myflag = true;    //create a flag

1.

if (empty($_POST["full_name"]))
    {
    echo $nameErr = "Full name is required"; // echo the error
    $myflag = false;   //change status of flag
    }

2.

if ( $myflag )
    {
    //if flag is true then insert data;
    $enter_sql = "INSERT INTO contact (full_name,contact_number,best_time_to_call) VALUES('$full_name','$contact_number','$best_time_to_call')";
    }
```

3.you are vulnerable to SQL injection if the data is directly inserted into database from a user

Comment: Would you please be able to explain your code to me?